# Dockerized pi-hole on ubuntu makes the connection unusable, is it expected?

Tags: virtualization, docker, raspberrypi, virtualbox-networking, container

In order to use pi-hole in a container on Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS I first download

```
docker pull pihole/pihole
```

then I free up some ports

```
sudo systemctl disable systemd-resolved.service && sudo systemctl stop systemd-resolved.service
```

then, to run it,

```
docker run -d --name pihole-cont -it -p 53:53/tcp -p 53:53/udp -p 67:67/udp -p 80:80 -p 443:443 -v "${DOCKER_CONFIGS}/dnsmasq.d/:/etc/dnsmasq.d/" -e ServerIP=[my IP address] --restart=unless-stopped --cap-add=NET_ADMIN --dns=127.0.0.1 --dns=1.1.1.1 pihole/pihole:latest"
```

When I open a browser and type

```
http://[docker's IP address]/admin
```

I do get to the pi-hole login page, even tho I don't know the password (I presume it's normal), however the connection gets unusable. It becomes impossible to navigate the internet, sites do start loading but it takes forever, video don't start earlier than at least five minutes, the span of my patience. I also successfully installed pi-hole in a virtual machine with the same results. I thought that the problem could have been a never ending loop: my computer makes a request, it goes through the DNS server, the DNS server is virtualized on my pc, so it makes a request to my pc and so on, even tho they had different IPs. This is similar, different IPs, unusable internet.

Is my guess correct or wrong? Am I doing something wrong? Is it even possible to *conteinerize* a pi-hole so that the internet is actually accessible?

Thank you in advance

EDIT: So, removing `--dns=127.0.0.1` makes the warning

```
WARNING: Localhost DNS setting (--dns=127.0.0.1) may fail in containers
```

go away. However simply disabling `systemd-resolved.service` breaks my internet anyway. If I `docker stop [pi-hole ID]` the internet stays broken, even tho I enable `systemd-resolved.service` again. The latter gives a port conflict warning. In order to retrieve my internet connection I purge all images and containers with

```
docker system prune -a -f --volumes
```

(very drastic but fast), restart `systemd-resolved.service`, and I can finally edit this question.

So the problem seems to be that I disable `systemd-resolved.service`, that has a port conflict with the container. How do I fix this?

Thank you again

Comment: Hello! do you get any error message, or something after any command? :)

Comment: Hello! No error messages. The only errors I got were related to used ports, so I had to shutdown apache and systemd-resolved.service. The messages I get are what is expected from each command =)

Comment: Hello again, I checked to be sure (bad memory here), I do get a warning: WARNING: Localhost DNS setting (--dns=127.0.0.1) may fail in containers.

Comment: its okay, I try to find related links as (believe it or not) I also have a PI but never tried to put it into use this way, and bad memory is alright thanks for verifying ; ill watch this question closely

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## It is easier to use `docker-compose`

Docker-compose allows you to keep all the parameters in a file and run the container as a normal user (not as `root`, do not need `sudo`).

Make sure docker-compose is installed:

```
sudo apt install docker-compose-plugin
```

Create a folder where the config file will go:

```
mkdir /home/$USER/pi-hole
cd /home/$USER/pi-hole
```

Note, `$USER` will be replaced by your username.

Then create the `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
nano docker-compose.yml
```

With the content of the file:

```
version: "3"
services:
  pihole:
    container_name: pihole
    image: pihole/pihole:latest
      hostname: pi-hole
    ports:
    - "53:53/tcp"
    - "53:53/udp"
    - "67:67/udp"
    - "80:80/tcp"
    - "443:443/tcp"
    environment:
    # Change the Time Zone to your area
    TZ: ‘America/New_York'
    # Change the password to suit your needs
    WEBPASSWORD: SecretPassword
    # Volumes store your data between container upgrades
    volumes:
    - './etc-pihole/:/etc/pihole/'
    - './etc-dnsmasq.d/:/etc/dnsmasq.d/'
    cap_add:
    - NET_ADMIN
    restart: unless-stopped
```

Make sure you **change the Time Zone and password** in the above text to suit your needs. The line `hostname: pi-hole` above determines what you see in the Pihole web portal. If you two or more instances of Piholes docker imagaes in different computers, it makes sense to name them different in the respective `docker-compose.yml` files.

Save and exit the editor by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> followed by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>.

Disable and stop systemd-resolved service. You seem to have done this already. I am keeping this for others:

```
sudo systemctl disable systemd-resolved.service
sudo systemctl stop systemd-resolved.service
```

Unlink and edit `resolv.conf`:

```
sudo unlink /etc/resolv.conf
sudo nano /etc/resolv.conf
```

When the file opens in the nano editor make sure the following line is commented out with a `#` in the front:

```
#nameserver 127.0.0.53
```

Save and exit the editor by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> followed by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>.

Test that DNS is working before starting Pi-hole:

```
ping -c4 google.com
```

If it works start pi-hole with the following command:

```
docker compose up -d
```

This will start start docker as a daemon (the `-d` option) and take the configuration of the container from the `docker-compose.yml` you created above.

If all goes well you should be able to open the Pihole web portal by going to:

```
http://[Your Ubuntu-Pihole computer's IP address]/admin/login.php
```

on your favorite web browser such as Firefox. Then you can set the DNS servers Pihole uses in its settings

[image]

Hope this helps

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for your answer, what if ```ping -c4 google.com
``` doesn't work? I'm running your instructions in a virtual machine, it otherwise worked before, I checked, thank you again!

Comment: Happy holidays! So I followed your guide, also I looked at this guide: ```https://github.com/pi-hole/docker-pi-hole/#running-pi-hole-docker``` which includes a port conflict workaround, while on a virtual machine. I did see a progress, namely pi-hole was running, internet was running smoothly, no port conflict was reported, however I couldn't set up the DNS specifics from the ubuntu settings, in particular docker didn't have a ipv6, just ipv4. While trying to watch some youtube videos I kept running into ads.

Comment: A new problem/thing also appeared, I could only reach ```http://[correct ip]/admin``` from the virtual machine, not from my ubuntu environment, something that I was able to do with a virtualized raspberry-pi, while messing with apache2, ssh,... In this case, while running the pi-hole on docker in a virtual machine, the ip was unusable from the 'outside'. Having said that, I ran out of ideas and sources =(
PS: ```docker-compose up -d``` works magnificently given that the port conflict workaround is handled as in the previous link

Comment: Pihole won't stop YouTube ads as those ads come from the same URL as the main video. What  virtual machine? You didn't say you were running docker in a VM.

Comment: You may want to ask a new question about accessing a web server (in your case, the Pihole admin page) running on a VM. Include details of the VM type, QEMU, VirttualBox, etc. in your question.

Comment: Thank you for your answers, I'm using ubuntu on virtualbox, I will look into the possibility of it working without my aknowledgment =)

Comment: You may want to read up on [how VirtualBox network works with the host](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html). Different networking modes would mean different way to connect to the Ubuntu VM in the VirtualBox from the host computer.